# Returning JSON values to objects IONIC v2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an API that returns a value based on a barcode scan function in Ionic V2. please see code snippet below:

```
getProduct(qrBarcode: string): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.ApiUrl}/product/read_product.php?barcode=${qrBarcode}`)
    .map(res => <Product[]>res.json());
}
```

I Use a function to integrate the search from the barcode scanner to the API Read like so:

```
scanCode(){
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {

this.scannedCode = barcodeData.text;
this.qrBarcode = this.scannedCode;

this.apiProvider.getProduct(this.qrBarcode).subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products;
  this.dosingRequirement = products[1].Dosage;
})
//test api calculations
this.totalVolume = this.tankVolume;
this.dosage = this.dosingRequirement * this.totalVolume;
}
```

the problem I am facing is I cannot break down the JSON so returns and return each part of the JSON as objects. Any help on this would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really get what you get in the output from the question. But it seems like you should try removing the `<Product[]>` from `.map(res => <Product[]>res.json())` so it is like this `.map(res => res.json())`, since `map` is acting on each element of the list and typecasting each element of the list to another list within (`Product[]`) doesn't make sense. If this doesn't fix it, may be try to create a reproduction of your problem or provide more info on what you are getting in the output vs a sample of what you expect in the output.

Hope it helps